# How to delete all cookie when visitor visit my website?

Tags: web

I want to ask a question: How to delete all cookie when visitor visit my website. I am using wordpress.
I searched a lot of question like this my question but I can't find a satisfactory answers.

Please help me ! Sorry for my poor English !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either retrieve and manipulate cookies on the server side using PHP or client side, using JavaScript.

In PHP, you set cookies using `setcookie()`. Note that this must be done before any output is sent to the browser which can be quite the challenge in Wordpress. You're pretty much limited to some of the early running hooks which you can set via a plugin or theme file (functions.php for example), eg

```
add_action('init', function() {
    // yes, this is a PHP 5.3 closure, deal with it
    if (!isset($_COOKIE['my_cookie'])) {
        setcookie('my_cookie', 'some default value', strtotime('+1 day'));
    }
});
```

Retrieving cookies in PHP is much easier. Simply get them by name from the `$_COOKIE` super global, eg

```
$cookieValue = $_COOKIE['cookie_name'];
```

Unsetting a cookie requires setting one with an expiration date in the past, something like

```
setcookie('cookie_name', null, strtotime('-1 day'));
```

For JavaScript, I'd recommend having a look at one of the jQuery cookie plugins (seeing as jQuery is already part of Wordpress). Try http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Cookie

and refer this too

http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Cookies

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_clear_auth_cookie

Comment: Thank you, but I want to delete all cookie of another website in visitor's computer when they visit my website. Is it possible ?

Comment: for what your trying to do this

Answer (score 2):

Most probably it's in PHP since it is WordPress platform. It's either using WordPress function or PHP function to do it.

```
 <?php wp_clear_auth_cookie(); ?>
```